# W10 usb sound system makes ticking sounds

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, usb, sound-card, clicking-sound

Here's a problem I am having for few months now:

1. Using USB Creative Katana soundbar connected to updated Windows 10 pc with newest software, firmware and drivers.
2. Few months ago I started hearing 'crackling'/'ticking' sound out of the blue, one day everything was OK, next day it started.
3. The sound does not sound like a static, just like a "ticking" echo sound, happens every few seconds when sound is playing, does not happen when no sound is playing.
4. Problem does not happen when soundbar is connected via bluetooth.
5. Problem does not happen on the same computer with ubuntu system ran from usb.

help :(

Edit.
Seems culprit was the cable - seemingly not broken anywhere, and fairly high quality cable, and yet when i replaced it with cheap phone charger cable I had lying around it fixed all the issues.

Comment: Sounds like somehow the latency when used with USB  causes audio interference. I would try to hook up the device using a different usb port and reinstall the drivers. You can also try setting the power management to High-Performance

Comment: I did try different usb and power settings, will give another go to reinstalling. thanks!

Comment: @LPChip reinstalling did not help either

Comment: One other thing that I can think of is a faulty USB cable. Can you replace the USB cable to test if that is the case?

Comment: @LPChip I will look for another cable, but why would the soundbar work right under Ubuntu, but not under Windows?

Comment: different drivers could make the ubuntu either filter out the cracks or make them very soft so you don't really hear them that were generated by a faulty cable

Comment: Please add an answer @LPChip, I will accept it as cable was the culprit.

Comment: What kind of host computer do you have? Intel? AMD?

Comment: @Ale..chenski intel, old i5-3570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a few things that are the problem here. It could be a driver issue for example.

If you plugin the device in a different USB port, windows should reinstall the drivers. Reinstalling software can also help.

It may also be just the cable being damaged and picking up interference. Ubuntu's drivers may be different enough to filter that out somehow.